# How to self host a UDP Policy server for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, wcf, iis, tcp, udp

I am trying to see how viable UDP is for development of a web based game.

[Andrea Boschin](http://www.silverlightplayground.org/post/2010/01/02/Writing-a-server-less-conferencing-client-with-Silverlight-40-UDP-Multicast.aspx) has a good example of a UDP solution. This solution works fine when run from the VS2010 debugged. This solution comprises of three projects

1. A console application which hosts the MulticastPolicyServer
2. A Silverlight client which talks to a UdpAnySourceMulticastClient
3. A web project to host the Silverlight client

My question: What do I need to do to host this on the **internet**? Do I need to deploy the policy server to IIS? Construct a windows service ? or is this a intranet only solution?

Comment: In other words : How can I expose the udp client to another udp client over the internet ?

Answer (score 0):

IIS is not meant for this purpose. You have to write a windows service to host your UDP program. And of course there restriction exposing UDP over the Internet. Just keep in mind that UDP is not reliable protocol and it can miss a packet. So your logic should be capable of handling this.

Comment: I have client A connecting from an internet domain.
I have client B connecting from another internet domain.
I have a policy server at www.xyz.com

How does client B access the udp packets from A without knowing the location of A?

Answer (score 0):

use an RPC protocol over TCP to setup a subscription/authentication service (it may be useful to read up on XMPP) - do a one time authentication (your best bet is probably X509 [SSL, HTTPS] via WCF) which would work like a passive FTP...connect to me (server) then I'll give you a new port to connect to where I'll (as in me, the server) will be broadcasting media - then use UDP as your transport mechanism for your video/audio assuming that's what you're trying to do

Comment: I gave this some more thought and realize I may have overcomplicated things - I'm not entirely sure if it would make sense to combine UDP and TCP. From some other posts I've read, a good area for you to check out might be Silverlight game development. It may also be worth looking into SCTP.